# Sorting a BsonArray of string

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a BsonArray of string of ID and I want to sort it so it appear ascending before saving to database

I am using C# driver of mongodb, below is the BsonArray.

```
"IDPart" : [ "BO0001", 
    "CO0001", 
    "BD0002", 
    "BD0001"]
```

so I think it will sorted out to be like this

```
"IDPart" : [ "BD0001", 
        "BD0002", 
        "BO0001", 
        "CO0001"]
```

I searched but only found sort BsonArray that contain BsonDocument, not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sort methods provided by .NET framework. For example:

```
var array = new BsonArray(new []
                {
                    "BO0001",
                    "CO0001",
                    "BD0002",
                    "BD0001"
                });

var sortedArray = new BsonArray(array.OrderBy(v => v.AsString));

foreach (var v in sortedArray)
    Console.WriteLine(v);
```